# How do you link a Twitter account with a Facebook PAGE?

Tags: facebook, twitter

How do you link a Twitter account with a Facebook *Page*?

I've done it before but I think they changed the process.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which way.

Facebook `->`Twitter is possible via http://www.facebook.com/twitter

The opposite way there is no official channel but many apps are available such as [Involver](http://www.involver.com/).

Answer (score 0):

the Twitter application appears to be working correctly again. Simply login to the Twitter application on Facebook (and under "connect your accounts" click on the "Sign in with Twitter" button), and you'll be able to connect Twitter to your Facebook account and post status updates to Twitter.